# Twitter получить историю по follower'ам

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

Хочу построить график Followers x Time
Подобно тому как это реализовано вконтакте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть ли для этого API, или только вытягивать снимки можно по крону?

Comment: Что из себя представляют Followers x Time?

Comment: Количество фолловеров по дням

Comment: Т.е. хочется дёргать пользователей, который посещали определённую страницу? не совсем понятная задача.

Comment: Есть список страниц, нужно узнать какое количество пользователей было подписано на неё в конкретный период времени. Например `['2017-01-20'=>'10', '2017-01-21'=>'11','2017-01-22'=>'11', '2017-01-23'=>'10', '2017-01-24'=>'9']` Тоесть. 5 дней назад у страницы было 10 подписчиков, а сегодня 9-ть, дальше буду строить по этим данным график

Comment: Twitter не предоставляет возможности получить соответствующие данные О_о?